Finitely generated left ideals of operator algebras
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A\subseteq B(H)$ be a non-selfadjoint operator algebra. For $a_1,a_2\in A$, suppose $L = Aa_1 + Aa_2$ is closed in $A$.

Q: Is $L = Ap$ for some $p\in A$?

This is the case if $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra.

No. Let $A = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}: a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$. Then,
$$L = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}: a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}\right\} = Ae_{11} + Ae_{12}$$
But for any $p = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in L$, one may easily check that $Ap = \mathbb{C}p \neq L$.
